# Shortcut for insert a cell below for Ipython in Pycharm?

Tags: ipython, pycharm

I just started using Ipython in Pycharm.

What's the shortcut for insert a cell for Ipython in Pycharm?

1. To insert a cell between the 2nd and 3rd cell.
2. To insert a cell at the end of code

According to Pycharm documentation, way to add cell as follows.
But it doesn't work for me. Anyone find the same issue?

Since the new cell is added below the current one, click the cell with import statement - its frame becomes green. Then on the toolbar click add (or press Alt+Insert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that is what you need, but you can insert cells above by `Ctrl+Shift+Equals` and below by `Ctrl+Equals`.

**Update**

All shortcuts for IPython Notebook are in Settings -> Keymap -> Plug-ins -> IPython Notebook

[image: Explanation image]

Comment: It works! @chinskiy is there a cheatsheet for shortcuts for Iphython in Pycharm? How did you find out this shortcut? Thank you!

Comment: For newer version of PyCharm, the settings are in `Settings` -> `Keymap` -> `Python`

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same concern and right now I remembered that you can just write #%% (for code cell) or #%% md (for markdown cell) anywhere you want and it will create a new cell