# Missing PyCharm keymapping options for my IPython Notebook plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ipython, keymapping

My goal is to remap IPython notebook key bindings from within PyCharm.

I can see that these options existed for at least some people as of a year ago because of the screenshot in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151292/shortcut-for-insert-a-cell-below-for-ipython-in-pycharm):
[image]
My PyCharm version is fully-up-to-date - although it is an evaluation version - could that be the reason?

What I see:[image]